# Append / Concatenate all rows in a single column in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dataframe

For context : I have multiple datasets files and each file belongs to single Dimension;
Goal: So for this i am trying to get all the rows of one Dataframe in a single column
Dataset looks like this
[image]

To have all the rows in a single column. I have following lines of code

```
 a = []
for x in range (5):
   np_df = df_D1.loc[x]
   a.append(np_df)
```

It gives me a result like this
[image]

But i want a result like this.

[image]

It kind of easy and feeling bit stupid and kind of a stuck here.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code and refrain from using images as much as possible.

Comment: Try `df.iterrows()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you could use a simple reshape here.
Assuming your `DataFrame` is named df

```
import numpy as np
a = np.expand_dims(df.values.reshape(-1),axis=1)
```

Use casting to `pandas.DataFrame`  if you desire a `DataFrame` as output:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(np.expand_dims(df.values.reshape(-1),axis=1))
```

Comment: Note that this solution should be at least an order of magnitude faster than for-loop based solutions due to vectorization in NumPy

Comment: You have highlighted a major point and you are right

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a method that does it in one line but you can use the pd.Series.values method :

```py
a = []
for x in range (5):
   np_df = df_D1.loc[x].values
   a.append(np_df)
```

This will only take the values and not the series as a whole.
Also to get the format you want you can :

```py
a = []
for x in range (5):
   series_values = df_D1.loc[x].values
   for val in series_values:
       a.append([val])
```

If I understood correctly this should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
# test df
data = {
    'channel_0_0': [1, 2, 3],
    'channel_0_1': [4, 5, 6],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

>>>     channel_0_0     channel_0_1
>>> 0   1   4
>>> 1   2   5
>>> 2   3   6

# go through rows
all_values = []
for idx, values in df.iterrows():
    all_values.extend(values)

all_values
>>> [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```